# message error: Cannot access mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

I am using snippetcompiler. I once added references to .NET 3.5 and the remove them but since I got this error each time I run a cs file:

cannot copy v2...\mscorlib.dll to c:\windows\system32

How to correct this if someone knows ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is trying to write files into system32, presumably as a working directory. Perhaps change the working directory? Or if the code is yours, write to temp...

I'm not sure why it would want to copy mscorlib, unless this is some kind of shadow-copy gone bad...